# source code of android market app

Tags: android, google-play

Can I get the complete source code of android market app, as it is an open source product...
please any one send me some links to download.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android is open source, but the Android Market App is not.

Comment: i wanted it bcz refer this link...........http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384449/launching-android-market-app-with-all-games-available

Comment: Sorry dude... as you can't see the code, it will be hard to do what you want. Even decompiling the market app code could be really hard.

Comment: yes i know its hard but i found the way to launch the android market app with all applications displayed...

Comment: i want to launch the market app with all games displayed..

Comment: all games and all apps in the market app are in the same List activity called,AssetBrowserActivity..whenever i try to launch all games instead of that all apps gets launched

Comment: Yes I know... launching an app is really easy. But, in order to make it open in the games section you need two things: pray that Market developers coded some way to do that (for instance, by reading something in the intent) AND find out how to do it (which is hard because you don't have the source code).

Comment: you mean to say it is impossible..there is no way..?

Comment: can i communicate directly to the market developers...?

Comment: All is possible... but this is hard to accomplish. I guess you can try to communicate with the market developers, but I don't know how.

Comment: ok thanks dude...have a great time..

Comment: @manju: please keep SO clean. It will be nice if you can spend some time here to see how people are using the site and following certain guidelines and standards...

Answer (score 1):

try [code.google.com/p/dex2jar/](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) and [code.google.com/p/apktool](http://code.google.com/p/apktool)